# 0.01mh-20H, Is that a good range for an inductance meter?

Tags: inductance, inductance-measurement

Inductance meters are relatively expensive for a student to afford,so, I decided to buy [ECR-T4](http://www.ebay.com/itm/12864-LCD-Mega328-ESR-Meter-Transistor-Tester-Diode-Triode-Capacitance-MOS-PNP-/111448748201) tester which happens to test inductors and measude their inductance.
I have no idea about its accuracy but i don't need accuracy right now.
My main interest is switching power supply, can this thing be a good device to start with?

Comment: The only known cheap portable working LCR meter is:  DER EE DE-5000. Don't waste money on fake meters, they don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't waste your money buying an inductor tester because it will not tell you many things that you need to get right when specifying an inductor for a switching power supply.

Instead, spend your money on buying the correct component from a reputable supplier.

Comment: To be fair, maybe he wants to wind his own inductors e.g. for ham radio operator reasons (I'd still follow your advice, but I haven't been taught RF tech curriculum from the late 40s like the rest of the ham world). But even in that case, something to measure the resonance frequency of a circuit is more handy than a inductance meter – and can be built with about any sound card, within physical boundaries.

Comment: He said switching power supplies and anyway a tester that had a lower limit of 10 uH wouldn't be much use for most air cored inductors. I'd be more interested in self resonance and a tester wouldn't tell you that.

Comment: Ah, true. yeah. for SMPS, value is almost newer critical, it just has to be "reliably high enough"; so yes, spend the extra.

Comment: as @MarcusMüller said , I have to wind my own inductor because simply there is no reputable supplier who buys these components with a wide range here (third world country issues)...

Comment: And I don't have any experience to even guess the value of an inductor. and, of course, I don't have a scope to use a frequency generator.

Comment: @MohannadMaklad Egypt might be struggling right now, but it's certainly not a third world country (by definition by the U.N. of "least developed countries"). But the political aspect of whether or not a Cold War term applies to a country aside: Mouser and all other global component distributors ship to Egypt. And I'm pretty sure you can also use google to look for "measure inductivity with resonance frequency", your English seems to be excellent!

Comment: You cannot expect decent performance with the correct value inductance measured at a standard test frequency because if the core material is unknown, you just will not know how it will perform when operated in the target circuit. Don't waste your money. The core material is more important than getting within 50% of the inductance value.

Comment: Can't stress that enough. What use is knowing the inductance well, at a operating point that has nothing to do with your actual usage? That's like conducting crash tests for cars by throwing fluffy bunnies at it and then saying "yes, this car is save up to 200k Fluffybunny units", when in reality, you'd need to test your car running into stone walls.

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, now I am searching for "measure inductivity with resonance frequency" and "third world and least devloped countries " :D i'm not good at these terms but i will consider shipping, thanks for the compliment though :)

Comment: well, I read this [article](http://www.cliftonlaboratories.com/self-resonant_frequency_of_inductors.htm) from clifton laboratories and in this [plot](http://i.imgur.com/MJh1kfU.gif) it doesn't seem that the inductance changes alot with frequency below the self-resonance frequency, am I missing something?

Comment: The inductor they tested is suitable for 90 mA and totally unsuited as the type of inductor for a buck converter or boost converter. Have you ever heard of core saturation? If not, I recommend that you look it up. Apart from anything else some cores may look identical to other cores but have a totally different pemeability making them either good at high frequencies or very lossy at high frequencies.

Answer (score 6):

10uH is a reasonable bottom limit for a low cost inductor tester. You get what you pay for (if you're lucky).

One thing you should be cautious about is the *frequency* it uses to test the inductor. Inductors, more than any other passive component, are fussy about their intended range of operating frequency. Iron-cored inductors will look bad at kHz frequencies. Ferrites, especially ones intended for SMPS use, will have higher losses at their intended operating frequencies than at low kHz. Unless you are measuring in the operating range of frequencies, treat loss measurements as nothing more than crude indications, and inductance measurements with suspicion. If you are lucky, that instrument will specify what frequency it uses. If you are *very* lucky, it will allow you to select it.

I certainly agree with the comments @marcus and @janka below that a scope is better than a cheap inductance meter for accurate measurements, but for $10, it's not going to be an either/or decision. I'd get the multi-function meter *and* get a scope and sig-gen when I could afford them.

Comment: I have to admit, I always use a frequency generator, arrange the coil under test and a selected capacitator into a series and use my scope to find the resonance peak. If one has the choice to buy a inductance meter or a frequency generator, always buy the latter one. It's simply much more useful.

Comment: Yep. And in that case, you might as well just think about getting a reasonably cheap oscilloscope (which one can use for many, many more things), use it to compare the unloaded input to the output of a LC oscillator, and drive it eg. with a sweep from your sound card, and determine inductance with the help of a reference capacitor at. It's not as comfy, but I honestly don't have to measure dozens of inductivities per day. Of course, if you're just looking for the peak, a sound card alone will do (if the operating freq is within the 40-22000Hz range)

Comment: And, since the OP stated that SMPS is the field of interest, specifying the current is also absolutely critical. Saturating the inductor during operation is not generally recommended.